# Fragment Tabs using Images

Tags: android-fragments

I am using Tabs in my Apps, but now its Deprecated, So now we are recommended to use FragmentTabs, and I found [this example](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/) to get started:

```
  // Tab titles

  private String[] tabs = { "Top Rated", "Games", "Movies" };
```

But my question is how can i use Images in place of Text in Fragment Tabs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use **SetIcon(R.drawable.icon)** to show Icon in place of Text in Fragment Tabs,

see this [example](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-actionbarsherlock-fragmenttabhost-tutorial/)

**Like:**

```
  // Create Tab1 with a custom image in res folder
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab1)),
            FragmentTab1.class, null);
```